# When does java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(...) throws SocketException?

Tags: java, sockets, exception

The documentation says that `Socket`'s `setSoTimeout(int)` method

> throws SocketException - if there is an error in the underlying protocol, such as a TCP error

Have you ever caught this exception? When using TCP sockets, what kind of TCP error could make this method throw the exception?

**EDIT**:

Let me try to be a bit more specific and deeper. I'm not looking for the trivial (eg, *a closed socket will throw this exception*) that can be easily found elsewhere.

Suppose the `Socket` (representing a TCP connection) has just been created, is connected, and not yet closed. I've not yet performed any reads/writes on it. I'm running on Linux (Ubuntu Server 11.04), so we can forget the case in which the TCP implementation doesn't support read timeouts.

Now, can this exception be thrown in this situation? If so, what does it mean? Is it something specific to the current `Socket` instance? If I simply `close()` it and somehow obtain a new one, should it work? Is it a bigger problem I cannot recover from (such as a problem in the operating system), and should better shutdown my application?

Comment: I believe Solaris doesn't support things like read timeout with setsocketopt. It should also throw in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The `SocketException`, in this scenario, is either thrown if the socket is closed or closing. 
It can also be thrown to indicate an error that was generated by the native TCP stack implementation. If, for instance, you are on Windows, `setSoTimeout` will likely boil down to an invocation of the `setsockopt` function in the Windows Winsock API. An error from this method would indicate some deeper issue in the winsock subsystem (unable to initialize) or it could also be thrown if you attempt to set socket options when a blocking operation is in progress on the socket (by another thread, for instance). For this reason, you should strive to only modify socket options at creation time, avoiding to change any options once you've connected the socket and started doing I/O on it.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you are curious.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.SocketException`is thrown when you call `setSoTimeout` on a closed socket.

As always, use the forc..[source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/Socket.java.html).

Comment: Sure, it is easy to see that from the code you linked. However, if the answer is really so simple and straightforward, why wouldn't the documentation be alike? If you go a little bit deeper, you will see that many of the methods called by `setSoTimeout`, including the native ones, can also throw the given exception. The answer I'm looking for is a little bit deeper.

Comment: I think if you do go deeper (i.e. concrete subclass of SocketImpl), you can no longer ask a generic question when `SocketException` is thrown - it depends. Now, in your edit you've defined your platform. I would go on and look into relevant bits of source. That _is_ the only reliable place to find your answer. JavaDoc is not very detailed, I agree, but it's because of 'it depends'-argument. I'm sorry if this sounds like being a wiseass, but I really do think that easiest way to find answer for this kind of 'it depends on implementation' is looking into the implementation.